# What is scored for bidding and making 3 Clubs Doubled?

Tags: bridge, scoring

- Bidder bids 3 Clubs.
- Opponent doubles.

No other bids.

Bidder makes 3 Clubs.

What is the Score the Bidder gets?

Comment: Welcome to Board and Card games Q&A.
I asume you target the game of bridge?

Answer (score 3):

The score varies by game variant:

#### Playing Rubber Bridge:

- Above the line - Insult: 50
- Below the line - Trick Score of: 120 as 3 * 40

The *trick score* for the deal equals or exceeds 100, so a game has been bid and made. If this game is the second by the same partnership of the rubber, an additional *Rubber Bonus* of either 500 or 700 would be scored *above the line*.

Presumably the disagreement inciting the question is to do with how to score the points earned as **doubled** - i.e. the trick score above points as 120 - 60. The [Rules of Rubber Bridge](https://cdn.acbl.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Laws-of-Rubber-Bridge.pdf) state clearly:

> #### Law 72 - Points Earned
>
> The result of each deal played is recorded in points,
>   which fall into two classes:
>
> A. *Trick Points*: Only declarer’s side can earn trick
>   points and only by fulfilling the contract. Only the
>   value of tricks named in the contract may be scored
>   as trick points (see Law 81). ....
>
> #### Law 81 - Scoring Table
>
> **TRICK SCORE**
>
> Scored below the line by declarer’s side, if contract
>   is fulfilled:
>
> For each Trick over six, bid and made ... Doubled [in Clubs]: 40
>
> ....
>
> **PREMIUM SCORE**
>
> Scored above the line by declarer’s side
>
> For winning the rubber, if opponents have won no game 700
>
> For winning the rubber, if opponents have won one game 500
>
> ...
>
> For making any doubled contract: 50
>
> ...

Further down it makes clear that the slam bonuses are scored only for contracts where 12 tricks (small slam) or 13 tricks (grand slam) have been both bid and made.

There are no further *premium points* scored as there were no overtricks made.

#### Playing Duplicate or Chicago

(The latter sometimes also termed *Four Deal* or *Party Bridge* scoring.)

- Not Vulnerable: 470 as 300 (game bonus) + 120 (trick score as above) + 50 (insult as above)
- Vulnerable:  670 as 500 (game bonus) + 120 (trick score as above) + 50 (insult as above)

There is a variant of Chicago scoring that makes use of above- and below-line scoring, but that is of no consequence on a hand where game is bid and made (ie trick score >= 100), as here.

Answer (score 2):

In **Duplicate Bridge** (contract Bridge) the most commonly played bridge.

**3 Clubs**
**Vulnerable** (red zone): **670** *(40+40+40+500+50p)*
**Not Vulnerable** (green zone): **470** *(40+40+40+300+50p)*

World Bridge Federation
[The Laws of Duplicate Bridge 2017](http://www.worldbridge.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/2017LawsofDuplicateBridge-nohighlights.pdf)

> LAW 77 – DUPLICATE BRIDGE SCORING TABLE (Page 57)
>   ...
>   Clubs
>   **40p** *For making each **Doubled** odd trick bid*...
>   ...
>   Premiums...
>   **500p** For making **GAME** Vulnerable
>   **300p** For making **GAME**, Not Vulnerable
>   **50p** For making any **Doubled**, but not Redoubled contract

*Note:

2 of a major doubled is game, as is 2NT and 3 of a minor.

When you bid such a contract and are doubled, you have been doubled into game, and you receive the full game bonus.*

Here's a couple of great scoring charts you can use:
[ptaff.ca - Duplicate Bridge Scoring Tables](https://ptaff.ca/bridge/duplicata/?lang=en_CA)
[No Fear Bridge - Duplicate Bridge Scoring](https://www.nofearbridge.co.uk/acol/duplicate_scoring.pdf)